# jQuery webcam : Flash settings "Remember"

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-webcam-plugin

I am looking at ["jQuery Webcam Plugin"](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) ( Looks like this is the most widely used webcam plugin)  for my project .

I am curious how to get "Remember" feature on the flash player settings . Do I have to modify Action Script and have to recompile for this ..?

For example if you look at google plus , here is the flash player screen shot

[image]

Thanks for your help